# Error occurs when loading the model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
2022-03-09 09:33:56.123970: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

f tensorflow/core/platform/default/env.cc:73] check failed: ret == 0 (11 vs. 0)thread tf_data_private_threadpool creation
Aborted.
```

When I running tensorflow while loading the model the error is occuring . Is there any solution

Comment: It might be a memory outage issue. You can increase your memory quota , use lite models  or increase the number of threads. Attaching relevant thread for reference.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41532#issuecomment-759075803   https://rudametw.github.io/blog/posts/2014.04.10/not-enough-threads.html